# .toLowerCase in javascript "not a function"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something like this

```
if (pathArray.toLowerCase().indexOf("blah") != -1{}
```

When debugging with console I get the error that "pathArray.toLowerCase is not a function". Why do I get that message?

Comment: Is `pathArray` an array?

Comment: `pathArray` is probably not a string. If it is an array, you probably want `pathArray.some(function(v) { return v.toLowerCase() === 'blah';});` .

Comment: [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is a function in String.prototype. Most likely your `pathArray` is a different type of object.

Comment: if `pathArray` is an array, `toLowerCase()` is a string method, you would need to traverse each element in array and convert it to lowercase. Also, you are missing a closing `)`

Answer (score 6):

`toLowerCase` is a method of the string. If you want to be able to find a string in array without knowing exact case you can add `map` step to the chain:

```
pathArray.map(function(s) { return s.toLowerCase(); }).indexOf('blah') !== -1
```

Answer (score 4):

toLowerCase() is only for strings, but I have a feeling that your "pathArray" is, in fact, an array.

```
> 'hello'.toLowerCase()
'hello'
> ['hi', 'bye'].toLowerCase()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Are you trying to check if "blah" exists in your array in any uppercase / lowercase form?

Comment: Hi yes, it is an array so that makes sens now that it would not work. I'm trying to make indexOf. case insensitive.

Comment: In that case, dfsq has given you the answer that you need!  S/he is iterating through the array and making a new one with all of the elements lowercase, then checking for 'blah'.

Answer (score 1):

The *toLowerCase* method belongs to the String function prototype. So probably pathArray isn't a String. I have the feeling (for its name) that is an Array. In that case the following code could be useful for you:

```
pathArray.forEach(function(item, index){
    if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf("blah") != -1){
    }
});
```

The code proposed by dfsq could be useful too. It depends on what level you want to perform the indexOf function. In my case you will be performing search over each string in order to find the start index of the sub string "blah". In the dfsq's code you will be looking the array index which contains the the entire string "blah".

Answer (score 0):

> yes, it is an array so that makes sens now that it would not work. I'm trying to make indexOf. case insensitive.

No need for `Array#indexOf()`:

```
if (pathArray.some(function(v) { return v.toLowerCase() === 'blah';}))
```

[`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns true if for any element the callback returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your String is probably resides in index 0 of an Array.

Appling toLowerCase() on the 0 index should solve your issue:

```
pathArray[0].toLowerCase()
```